# How to catch (or suppress) "PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large" error in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I know you can try to handle this error by adding `{limit: '50mb'}` (or some other very large limit) to the body-parser middleware, but this doesn't actually solve the problem as an attacker can send data of size 51mb and they will receive a HTTP 413 response with the exception, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
<pre>PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at readStream (/some/path/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at getRawBody (/some/path/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at read (/some/path/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:77:3)<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at textParser (/some/path/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/text.js:86:5)<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/some/path/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (/some/path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at /some/path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (/some/path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/some/path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at expressInit (/some/path/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/some/path/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (/some/path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at /some/path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (/some/path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/some/path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)<br> 
&nbsp; &nbsp;at query (/some/path/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js:45:5)</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

This obviously is very bad as it's giving the attacker information about my setup.

1. How can I catch (or suppress) PayloadTooLargeError?
2. How can I tell Node.js to (in general) not return any exceptions in HTTP responses?

Thanks

Comment: If you install your own [Express error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), you can decide what you want to send back to the client for any specific error or all errors.  It seems to me that you're a bit misguided in thinking that you need to "hide" a 413.  It's not clear at all how that helps you.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your reply. We need to hide all errors as our product unfortunately will be targeted by attackers, so we need to minimise all responses to their probes.

Comment: I think you're misguided to think that hiding a 413 helps you in any meaningful way.  Anyone who wants to know what the payload limit is can just keep increasing the payload size until the request fails - regardless of the status code returned.  You're not hiding anything.  And, if you have legitimate developers using your API, hiding the cause of the error will drive them nuts and be very unproductive for them.

Comment: @jfriend00 How will they know the request failed if I return a success status code upon their failure? The only people using our API are us, so we don't need to return any useful information to anyone. As stated, we don't want to return any useful information at all. If you knew what our product was you'd agree with me.

Comment: Well, I guess I can't participate in this discussion any more since you're not revealing what the product is.  I hope you don't have any legitimate developers trying to use an API that doesn't report errors.

Comment: @jfriend00 The only people using our API is us, so there is no need to worry about other developers getting weird HTTP responses. I agree that would be extremely frustrating for them, and bad form from us.

Answer (score 0):

Influenced by @jfriend00 in the comment above, here is the solution:

1. How can I catch (or suppress) PayloadTooLargeError?

Add middleware such as the following to at the end of your middleware routes:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.sendStatus(YOUR ERROR CODE HERE);
  }
  next();
});
```

2. How can I tell Node.js to (in general) not return any exceptions in HTTP responses?

Add the following environment variable:

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```